# creating service principal in azure with certificate

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to follow azure documetation to create sp:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal-cli

Followed steps for sp using certificate method until here and facing the error when I execute this command:
azure ad sp create -n exampleapp --cert-value {certificate data}

```
> rawStack: [Getter] } Error   <<< async stack >>>   at __1
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/arm/ad/ad.servicePrincipals.js:174:41)   at __3
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/arm/ad/ad.servicePrincipals.js:172:30)   <<< raw stack >>>
>     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-graph/lib/operations/servicePrincipals.js:128:19
>     at retryCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/ms-rest/lib/filters/systemErrorRetryPolicyFilter.js:89:9)
>     at retryCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/ms-rest/lib/filters/exponentialRetryPolicyFilter.js:140:9)
>     at handleRedirect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/ms-rest/lib/filters/redirectFilter.js:39:9)
>     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/ms-rest-azure/lib/filters/rpRegistrationFilter.js:59:14
>     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/utils.js:613:7
>     at handleRedirect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/utils.js:590:9)
>     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/logging.js:331:7
>     at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/ms-rest/lib/requestPipeline.js:125:16)
>     at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
```

Comment: Have you install Azure CLI 1.0? please ust this command to check it `azure --version`.

Answer (score 1):

For now, Azure have **CLI 1.0** and **CLI 2.0**.

CLI 1.0 command like this: `azure ad sp`

CLI 2.0 command like this: `az ad sp`

We can use this command to check it: `azure --version` or `az --version`

If you install CLI 2.0, we can use this command to create SP:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name {appId} --password "{strong password}"
```

More information about use CLI 2.0 to create SP, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

---

**Update**:

If you want to use CLI 1.0 to create SP, the `--cert-value` represents the **base 64 encoded** certificate.

We can use PowerShell to encoding it, please refer to this [link](https://adsecurity.org/?p=478).

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)